# Proving $|\sin x - \sin y| < |x - y|$

Tags: calculus, inequality

From Spivak's Calculus:

> Prove that $|\sin x - \sin y| < |x - y|$ for all $x \neq y$. Hint: the same statement, with $<$ replaced by $\leq$, is a straightforward consequence of a well-known theorem.

Now, I might even be able to prove this somehow (?), but I can't seem to figure out what "well-known theorem" the author is alluding to here... any hints?

Comment: The hint is pointing at the mean value theorem.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Maybe it's referring to the [mean value theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mean_value_theorem).

Comment: This doesn't give an answer, so this would be more appropriate as a comment.

Comment: Well, I suppose it's quite strightforward how to use the mvt to get the inequality, isn't it?

Comment: Sure it is, but it doesn't solve the problem.

Comment: Sorry, I thought the autor was just asking which was the theorem, not to solve the problem.

Comment: Okay, you have a point there.

Comment: Thanks... and yes, I just wanted to "get" the hint, so I will accept this as an answer

Answer (score 18):

You don't actually need Calculus to prove it:

$$|\sin x - \sin y| = \left| 2 \sin \frac{x-y}{2} \cos\frac{x+y}{2} \right| \,.$$

The inequality $\left| \sin \frac{x-y}{2}\right|< \left|\frac{x-y}{2}\right|$ is well known, while  $\left|\cos\frac{x+y}2\right|\leq 1$ is even more well known. The first inequality is sharp if $x-y \neq 0$.

Comment: I guess the second inequality should read $|\cos(\frac{x+y}{2})| \leqslant 1$, without strict inequality.

Comment: Yep, that's what I meant, the first one is strict :) Thank you Davide for fixing it.

Comment: But is it possible to prove it using calculus? If possible could you please give a hint on how to do that?

Comment: @Adithya Just apply MVT to $\sin(x)$.

Answer (score 15):

If $x<y$ then one has
$$\left|{\sin y-\sin x\over y-x}\right|=\left|{1\over y-x}\int_x^y\cos t\>dt\right|\leq\int_0^1 \bigl|\cos\bigl(x+\tau(y-x)\bigr)\bigr|\>d\tau<1\ ,$$
because the integrand is $\leq1$, but not $\equiv1$.

Answer (score 1):

Define
$f(x)=\sin x$.

Start with the case $y>x$ :

Note that $f(x)$ is everywhere continuous and differentiable, in particular in the interval [x,y] (y>x). By the mean value theorem (sometimes referred to as Lagrange's rule) $\exists$ a point $c\in(x,y)$  such that
$$f(y)-f(x)=f'(c)\cdot(y-x)\ ,$$
i.e.
$$\sin y-\sin x=\cos c\cdot (y-x)\qquad\Rightarrow\qquad |\sin y-\sin x|=|\cos c|\cdot | y-x| \ .$$
But
$|\cos c|\leq 1$
hence
$$|\sin y-\sin x|=|\cos c|\cdot | y-x|\leq |y-x|\ .$$

For the case $x>y$  the argument is analogous to the $y>x$ case.
For $x=y$ it is trivially true.