# Show that a set is dense in $[-1,1]$

Tags: real-analysis

Show that $\{\cos\ n:n \in \mathbb{N}\}$ is dense in $[-1,1]$ by using the fact below:

> Suppose $x$ is irrational. Then there exists $p_n,q_n \in \mathbb{Z}$
>   such that $\bigg|x -\frac{p_n}{q_n}\bigg| < \frac{1}{q_n^2}$

I have no idea on how to apply the fact above to show the set is dense in $[-1,1]$. Can anyone help me?

Comment: Presumably $q_n \to \infty$ as $n \to \infty$?

Comment: Yes, we know that fact. But we do not know how to apply that to show that the sequence is dense in $[-1,1]$.

Comment: In similar way can we say that the set $\{\sin n:n\in \mathbb N\}$ is dense in $[-1,1]$ ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We have that $|\cos x-\cos y|\le |x-y|$ for all $x,y$, by the mean value theorem. This can also be established without calculus; see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/92032/462) for the analogous proof for $|\sin x-\sin y|\le |x-y|$.

We know that $\cos(x)$ takes all values between $-1$ and $1$ as $x$ varies between $0$ and $2\pi$, so given $t\in[-1,1]$ begin by finding $x$ in $[0,2\pi)$ with $\cos x=t$. Fix $\epsilon>0$. We want to show that there is an $n$ such that $|t-\cos n|<\epsilon$. Note that $\cos (x+2\pi m)=t$ as well for any $m\in\mathbb Z$. If, for some $n$, $|(x+2\pi m)-n|<\epsilon$, we are done, since
 $$ |t-\cos n|=|\cos(x+2\pi m)-\cos n|\le|(x+2\pi m)-n|<\epsilon. $$
(The sign of $n$ is irrelevant here, since $\cos(n)=\cos(-n)$.)

Suppose then that this is not the case. Fix $k$ with $1/k<\epsilon$, so we are assuming that $(x+2\pi m)-n|\ge 1/k$ for any $m,n$. Consider the sequence $x_m=\{2\pi m\}$, where $\{r\}$ denotes the [fractional part](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fractional_part) of $r$. There must be $m<l$ such that $|x_m-x_l|<1/k$. This is simply because if we look at more than $N$ numbers between $0$ and $1$, two of them must be within $1/N$ of each other. Since $\pi$ is irrational, we also have $0<|x_m-x_l|$. Finally, note that $|x_m-x_l|=|2\pi(m-l)+c|$ for some integer $c$.

Write $s$ for $|x_m-x_l|$. Now look at the numbers $x,x+s,x+2s,x+3s,\dots$. Since all of them have the form $x+2\pi a+b$ for some $a,b\in\mathbb Z$, we must have that they are all at distance at least $1/k$ from any integer. Given $n\in\mathbb N$, let $M\in\mathbb Z$ be such that $M+1/k\le x+ns\le M+1-1/k$. Note that $M+1/k< x+(n+1)s< M+1$, since $0<s<1/k$. But then $x+(n+1)s\le M+1-1/k$ as well. This is of course absurd, because by induction it means that if $M+1/k\le x\le M+1-1/k$, then the same inequalities hold replacing $x$ with $x+ns$ for any $n\in\mathbb N$.

The above appears to avoid the density fact you are given ([Dirichlet's approximation theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirichlet%27s_approximation_theorem)), though the argument in the third paragraph is just its proof. If one wants to use the density fact explicitly, note that $2\pi$ is irrational, so there are arbitrarily large $q$ for which there is a $p$ with $$ \left|2\pi-\frac pq\right|<\frac1{q^2}. $$
Pick such a $q$ large enough so that $1/q<\epsilon$, let $s=|2\pi q-p|$, and proceed with the fourth paragraph.

Comment: Your statement of Dirichlet is wrong (the correct version - if one adds $q_n\to\infty$ - is in the problem statement). For $x=\sqrt 2$ and $q=4$ there is no integer $p$ with $\left|\sqrt 2-\frac p4\right|<\frac1{16}$.

Comment: You are right. Fixed now.

Comment: @AndresCaicedo: Why can we write $x=zq$? Also what is $z$? is it irrational?

Comment: You first define $z$ through $x=zq$ where $x$ and $q$ are fixed, and then try to find $p$ and $q$ such that... There seems to be something wrong in this. If it is another $q$ now, then this does not imply $|x-p|<\epsilon$, but if it is the same, then it is equivalent to writing find $q$ large enough so that $|x/q-p/q|<1/q^2$, which you cannot possibly do for arbitrary $x$ and large enough $q$.

Comment: Yes, that was circular, of course. It felt too easy to be right. I'll write a correct version in the morning.

Comment: (Hopefully fixed now. I'm making this CW since it is just Harald's hint fleshed out.)

Comment: Seems OK now. Though I am still wondering if we could avoid approximating irrational numbers.

Comment: I have posted an alternative way to prove this, which seems to avoid the necessity to approximate any particular irrational number (provided it is correct, of course).

Comment: @Vadim, your solution is approximating $2\pi$, and using its irrationality, isn't it?

Comment: @AndresCaicedo Could you kindly explain why $|x_m-x_l|=|2\pi(m-l)+c|$ for some integer $c$?

Comment: @ireallydonknow By definition, $x_m$ is $2\pi m-n$, where $n$ is the integer part of $2\pi m$. Same for $x_l$.

Comment: Just wondering does the fact given in the question implies that we can approximate all the numbers between [-1,1] with 2*\pi*x. If so, doesn't that straight away imply that sin x is dense? Why do you have to go through such a complicated proof?

Comment: @user136266 Precisely what form of approximation do you have in mind? The range of sine is not just dense, it is all of $[-1,1]$. How exactly is that giving us that $\{\sin(n)\mid n\in\mathbb N\}$ is dense? How exactly does knowing that this set is dense give us that also $A=\{\cos(n)\mid n\in\mathbb N\}$ is dense? It appears to me that if one tries to prove that $A$ is dense in the most straightforward way possible, one is led to something pretty close to the proof above. In that sense, it is not a complicated proof, but the natural approach.

Comment: In similar way can we say that the set $\{\sin n:n\in \mathbb N\}$ is dense in $[-1,1]$ ?

Comment: @Panja.S. Yes, the same argument works.

Answer (score 3):

**Hint:** $\pi$ is irrational, and the cosine function has period $2\pi$. Try to approximate any $\theta\in[0,2\pi]$ with numbers of the form $n-2m\pi$, for integers $m$, $n$.

Answer (score 3):

Suppose this is not true. Then there is an open interval $V$ in $[-1,1]$ such that $\cos\mathbb{N}\cap V=\emptyset$. Since $\cos:[0,\pi]\rightarrow[-1,1]$ is continuous and surjective, the preimage $U=\cos^{-1}V$ is a non-empty open set in $[0,\pi]$ such that for every $n,m\in\mathbb{Z}$: $n-2\pi m\not\in U$. Since $U$ is open and non-empty, it contains an $\epsilon$-width subinterval $\Delta$ for some $\epsilon>0$. If we show that some point $n-2\pi m$ falls into $\Delta$, this will lead to contradiction.

Using the fact stated in the problem, for any $N$ there are $p,q\in\mathbb{Z}$ such that $q>N$ and $0<|2\pi-\frac{p}{q}|<\frac{1}{q^2}$ or $0<\delta=|2\pi q-p|<\frac{1}{q}$. Let's choose $N$ large enough, so that $\delta<\frac{1}{q}<\frac{1}{N}<\epsilon$. Then, for some $k\in\mathbb{N}$: $|2\pi\cdot kq-kp|=k\delta$ falls into the $\epsilon$-width subinterval $\Delta$. We may choose the signs of $q$ and $p$ so that $0<2\pi\cdot kq-kp=k\delta\in\Delta\subseteq U$. This contradiction concludes the proof.

Answer (score 0):

This is the accepted answer but it is an abridged version.

Since the function cosine is continuous and even it is enough to show that the set of the  ***smallest angle*** of the integers , defined below, are dense in $ (0,2\pi)$.

$\overline{\underline{n}}:=n-2\pi p_n$ such that  $p_n$ is the only integer such that  $0\leq \overline{\underline{n}}< 2\pi $.

Arguing by contradiction, suppose that there is a $\theta\in (0,2\pi)$ and a $k\in \mathbb{N}$, such that $\overline{\underline{q}}\notin\left(\theta-\frac{1}{k},\theta+\frac{1}{k}\right)$ for every $q\in \mathbb{Z}$.

Since there are infinity angles $\overline{\underline{n}}$ in the interval $(0,2\pi)$ and no repetitions since $\pi$ is irrational. Two of these numbers satisfies $0<|\overline{\underline{n}}-\overline{\underline{m}}|\leq 1/k$, let's call this small positive number $\epsilon$.

It is not difficult to see that there is a positive integer $r\in \mathbb Z$ such that $r\epsilon\in\left(\theta-\frac{1}{k},\theta+\frac{1}{k}\right)$.

Notice that $r\epsilon=|r(m-n)-2\pi(p_m-p_n)|$, that is,  $r\epsilon=\overline{\underline{q}}$ for some $q \in \mathbb{Z}$, absurd since we assumed that there is no $\overline{\underline{q}}$ in this interval near to $\theta$.