# Limsup & liminf of $\exp(-\cos(n))$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, limits, analysis, limsup-and-liminf

Let $a_n = \exp(-\cos(n))$. I need to find $\limsup_{n \to \infty}(a_n)$ and $\liminf_{n \to \infty}(a_n)$.

By applying the definition of $\limsup$ I got that: $$\limsup_{n \to \infty}(a_n) = \lim_{n \to \infty}(\sup_{n\ge m}(a_n)),$$ which should intuitively be $e$, and similarly the $\liminf$ should be $\frac{1}{e}$. How should we prove these statements?

Comment: This link should be helpful: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1110073/how-to-prove-the-set-cosn-mid-n-in-mathbbn-is-dense-in-1-1

Comment: Hint with lack of strictness : If $f$ is strictly increasing smooth function, then $$\limsup f(a_n)=f(\limsup a_n)$$