# Limit of sequence

Tags: sequences-and-series

The sequence with $n$th term is given below
Consider the sequence $A_n = \sin n$ then

(a) The series is convergent as $n\to\infty$

(b) The series is divergent as $n\to\infty$

(c) $\lim_{n\to\infty} \text{ infimum} \sin(n) = 0$

(d) $\lim_{n\to\infty} \sin n = –1$

Comment: What is your opinion about this ?

Comment: according to me none of the option is right...

Comment: How can it be neither convergent nor divergent? (Note: It doesn't have to go to $\infty$ to be divergent.)

Comment: Don't know whats the solution and how to solve this?.

Comment: It could be nice to know what is **your** definition of divergent: sometimes, it means the sequence *diverges* to infinity or minus infinity, some other times it means it doesn't have a *finite* limit (no, it's not the same).

Comment: I agree with @DonAntonio. (b) could be false depending on the definition of *divergent*.

Comment: none of the option seems to be correct

Answer (score 2):

It is answer b). We have $$\limsup_{n \to \infty} \sin(n) = 1$$ and $$\liminf_{n \to \infty} \sin(n) = -1$$ Hence $$\limsup_{n \to \infty} \sin(n) \neq \limsup_{n \to \infty} \sin(n)$$ and thus the sequence $\left(\sin(n)\right)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ is divergent.

As a legitimation, I found the part below in Krantz, Real Analysis and Foundations:

[image]

Comment: it may diverge but i think we can't say it diverges to infinity...

Comment: (1) "Divergent" may depend on the given definition of this term, and (2) How  would you prove both limits (sup and inf.) equal that?

Comment: @DonAntonio I am not sure at the moment, I have to think about this. But I've added the reference which I've remembered (which lead me to this statement).

Comment: @TheGeekGreek The limits are correct, but their formal proof is pretty tough.

Comment: @DonAntonio Found it here: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/656930/show-that-a-set-is-dense-in-1-1. Yeah, pretty tough. I do not really like such proofs to be honest.