# How close does the maximum element of the sequence $a_n=\cos(n)$ get to 1?

Tags: sequences-and-series, trigonometry

$\{a_n\}$ is a sequence such that $a_n=\cos(n)$ with $n∈Z^+$. What I want is to prove that $\max(\cos(n))\to1$ (and also $\min(\cos(n))\to-1$). I thought I could choose $n=\lfloor{\pi\times2\times10^M}\rfloor$ with $M∈Z^+ $ and that $\lim_{M\to\infty} \cos(\lfloor{\pi\times2\times10^M}\rfloor)=\lim_{M\to\infty}\cos(\pi\times2\times10^M)=1$ would hold, but I now realize that $\lim_{M\to\infty}\{\pi\times2\times10^M\}$ does not converge to $0$, making my attempt incorrect. Am I even correct in assuming that $\max(\cos(n))\to1$?

Comment: I used $\cos(n)$ in place of $a_n$ as the former is the definition of the latter, so $\max(\cos(n))$ is just $\max(a_n)$. ($\max()$ refers to the maximum value whatever inside of the parenthesis can get)

Comment: Depending on what you mean by $Z^+$ this could be trivial because $cos(0)=1$.

Comment: Your max notation is off, I think you mean $$h(n)=\max\{\cos(i) : 1\leq i \leq n\}$$ and you want to show $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} h(n)=1$.

Comment: Yes, your assumption that $\sup \{ \cos n \mid n \in \Bbb Z^+ \}=1 $and $\inf \{ \cos n \mid n \in \Bbb Z^+ \} = -1$ is correct.  The set of all $\cos n$ is in fact dense in $[0, 1]$.  https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/656930/show-that-a-set-is-dense-in-1-1?noredirect=1&lq=1

Comment: @Michael  $Z^+$ refers to positive integers here so $n=0$ is not an answer sadly. I'm also unsure about how the max notation should be shown, so you might be correct. In any case, my goal is to find the lowest number that's bigger than or equal to every element of the sequence $\{a_n\}$

Comment: You want to find integers $n$ for which $n \approx 2\pi k$ for some integer $k$. Consider rational approximations of $\pi$.

Comment: @Michael the problem with that approach is that it's not possible to get rid of the digits after the decimal point of 2.

Comment: @RobertShore's answer can be reached by following the replies to the question this post is a duplicate of.